# URL parameters not passed within http request (Struts)

Tags: parameter-passing, httprequest, struts-1, url-parameters

I have a problem getting URL parameter using Struts 1.2/1.3.

I use the URL **myUrl/logon.jsp?myParam=123** which goes into the FormBean-reset()-function

`public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {...}`

But the request-parameterMap is empty and I do not find the myParam nor the value.
Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you show us the front-end HTML as well?

Comment: Which part do you need? The whole file is too long for pasting here.Edit: Find it here: https://filehorst.de/d/dvevuIIq

Comment: The part that shows the problem.

Comment: @faber The page you provided is in German, please provide the raw HTML.

Comment: In the meantime some little wonder happened. Or Netbeans debugger fooled me. When entering the reset()-method it showed me an empty parameter map in the request. Now I found that stepping through the code within this method "filled" the map although I did not touch the map. So probably I have been fooled.Thx anyway.